# Beginner Javascript: What's the difference between 'function xyz(){}' and 'var xyz = function(){}'?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

I've been going through CodeAcademy's Javascript courses, and a few things have gone over my head. I understand how function work, and I'm trying to wrap my head around OOP and objects/methods.

My question is, what's the difference between creating a function like this:

```
function countTo(number){
    for (var i=1; i<=number; i++){
        console.log(i);
    }
}

countTo(15);
```

and creating a function like this:

```
var countToTwo = function(number){
    for (var i=1; i<=number; i++){
        console.log(i);
    }
};

countToTwo(27);
```

Both do the same thing and have the same output. Are they exactly the same/interchangeable? Does it matter which one I use when creating a function?

Comment: You are correct - didn't show up for me because the original question wasn't descriptive enough! Thanks.

Comment: No problem, it's nice to be redirected to a nice descriptive answer like that.

Answer (score 8):

The first one is a function declaration, and is "hoisted", meaning it's immediately available anywhere in the context.

The second one is a function expression, and is treated just like any other variable declaration/assignment.  The *declaration* of `countToTwo` is hoisted and immediately available anywhere in the scope in which it's declared, but the *assignment* stays in exactly the same place.

The short of it is that you're not able to call a function declared as an expression until the expression has been parsed.

This code should illustrate a little more clearly.

```
foo();

//blah();

function foo(){
    alert('hoisted and works');
}

var blah = function(){
    // not hoisted, would fail if called
}
​
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nrjfs/1/)